# how to pass PEM certificate as first arg of i2d_X509

Tags: c, openssl, certificate

I'm creating self-signed certificate by:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cert.pem -days 1095
```

How do I pass cert.pem to i2d_X509?
I need something like:

```
 len = i2d_X509(".\cert.pem", &buf);
```

but my certificate in a PEM file..

Here is my code: (I used the example in https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html)

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int len,i;
    unsigned char *buf;

    buf = NULL;
    len = i2d_X509((X509*)".\cert.pem", &buf);

    if (len < 0){
        printf("error len < 0");
        return -1;
     }

    printf("buf:");
    for (i = 0; i < len ; i++)
        printf("0x%02X", *(buf+i));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: int d2i_X509_fp(FILE *fp, X509 *x); for files that are in DER/BER to get them in openssl internal C structure format ( neither PEM or DER ). format to get a DER output you can ask -outform DER ( openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cert.der -outform DER -days 1095 )

Comment: You've been a member for 3 years, asked 47 questions, but never accepted any of the answers which have helped?.  It is never too late to start.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I pass cert.pem to i2d_X509? ...

You don't/can't. You need to read the certificate with `PEM_read_bio_X509`. `PEM_read_bio_X509` returns an `X509*`. Then you can pass it to `i2d_X509`.

Be sure to call `X509_free` on the pointer when done with it.

Or, do as Philippe suggests - convert it to ASN.1/DER and then use it with `d2i_X509_fp`.

Also see the OpenSSL man pages on the [PEM Read/Write](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html) functions.

Comment: I did something like:
FILE *fp = fopen("cert.pem", "r");
X509 *x = PEM_read_X509(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
len = i2d_X509(x, &buf);
for (i = 0; i < len ; i++)
 printf("0x%02X, ", *(buf+i));
Is this OK ? because something in my authentication process fails and I'm trying to find what it is...